# Limit number of records php - flat file

Tags: php, flat-file

I am using flat file db, not mysql so I can't use $limit

I need to limit the number of records to 1, if more than 1 then echos something else:

```
$result = $db->getall(lmonth);
foreach($result as $item)
     show_record($item);
}
```

Function getall()

```
 /*!
    * @function getall
    * @abstract retrieves all records in the database, each record in an array
        * element.
    * @param orderby  order the results.  Set to the field name to order by
    * (as a string). If left unset, sorting is not done and it is a lot faster.
    * If prefixed by "!", results will be ordered in reverse order.  
    * If orderby is an array, the 1st element refers to the field to order by,
    * and the 2nd, a function that will take two take two parameters A and B 
        * - two fields from two records - used to do the ordering.  It is expected 
    * that the function would return -ve if A < B and +ve if A > B, or zero 
    * if A == B (to order in ascending order).
    * @param includeindex  if true, an extra field called 'FFDB_IFIELD' will
    * be added to each record returned.  It will contain an int that specifies
    * the original position in the database (zero based) that the record is 
    * positioned.  It might be useful when an orderby is used, and an future 
    * operation on a record is required, given it's index in the table.
    * @result all database records as an array
    */
   function getall($orderby = NULL, $includeindex = false)
   {
      if (!$this->isopen)
      {
         user_error("Database not open.", E_USER_ERROR);
         return false;
      }

      // If there are no records, return
      if ($this->records == 0)
         return array();

      if (!$this->lock_read())
         return false;

      // Read the index
      $index = $this->read_index();

      // Read each record and add it to an array
      $rcount = 0;
      foreach($index as $offset)
      {
         // Read the record
         list($record, $rsize) = $this->read_record($this->data_fp, $offset);

         // Add the index field if required
         if ($includeindex)
            $record[FFDB_IFIELD] = $rcount++;

         // Add it to the result
         $result[] = $record;
      }

      $this->unlock();

      // Re-order as required
      if ($orderby !== NULL)
         return $this->order_by($result, $orderby);
      else
         return $result;
   }
```

Function show_record()

```
   function show_record($record){
      $month = $record["lmonth"];
      $status = $record["lstatus"];
      $year = $record["lyear"];
   }
if (($status == ON) && ($month >= $current_month) && ($year >= $current_year)){
 echo "foo";
 }
```

I tried to use `break` but it comes back 0(zero) records.

I tried using `$i = 0`...but it returned all or nothing

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Tell us more about what `getall()` and `show_record()` do?

Comment: I just added getall() and show_record() above...

Comment: and why don't you use mySql ?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
function getall($orderby = null, $includeindex = false, $limit = null) {

    ...

    if ($orderby !== null) {
        $result = $this->order_by($result, $orderby);
    }
    if ($limit) {
        return array_slice($result, 0, $limit);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: deceze, $limit returned the first record-key and not the record the if statement is calling

Comment: @cchap I overlooked the ordering that requires to read all records beforehand, updated answer.

Comment: I just added the if statement below the function show_record()

Comment: I got to print the record I want by doing: $result = $db->getall(lp_month);
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $item){
     show_record($item);
     if($i>=2) break;
}
but I couldn't make it stop after 1

Comment: I made the update, but still only the first record, when I turned the first record OFF ($status) I got the blank page....so it didn't move to the next record. The closest result I got was when I used $i = 0 at the foreach(), but it didn't stop from showing multiple records when true

Comment: @cchap Your `show_record` functions seem nonsensical, are you sure your problem isn't simply in there? Try `var_dump` on the results of `getall`.

Comment: I tried var_dump too, but it didn't work. Here is the deal, when calling the record by clicking the link from the queue result it works perfectly, the problem is when doing dynamically, apparently it ignores some of the if statement commands, I also tried switch() same case. I tried java approach too, trying to mimic the action of > queue result > click record desired > shows record...but I couldn't find any script that would do the 3 actions on body onload().

Comment: @cchap Honestly, I give up. If *nothing* "works" for you, you're doing something wrong. You also seem to be all over the place at once. Try some step by step debugging (using `var_dump` for example).

Comment: I hear you, but this is the only thing holding my project, I am on this problem for the past 48-hrs, so literally I am all over the place. At this point I would settle for an ERROR MESSAGE if result is greater than 1...this is my goal for tomorrow...you gave me some ideas, thanks!!

Comment: I may know where the problem is...the if statement is been called after the foreach, tomorrow I will try to tweak the foreach to include the if statemente to see if it works, but then I will have the problem with the show_record()

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

Print_r did the trick, and I was using echo:

```
   print_r (show_record($row));
```

Here is how the final code is working for me:

```
$result = $db->getall(lp_month,lp_year);
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $row){
   print_r (show_record($row));
if ($i >= 1) 
 break;
$i++;
}
```

Now looking forward to solve other minor problems, thanks